# How to connect button to a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Buttons are not adding or subtracting from counterValue

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font

# main Window using Tk
win = Tk()

win.title("Counter")
win.geometry('500x500')

counterValue = 0

def plus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue += 1

def minus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue -= 1

counter = Label(win, text=counterValue)
counter.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
counter.place(x=250, y=50)

plus = Button(win, text="+", command=plus)
plus.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
plus.place(x=150, y=200)

minus = Button(win, text="-", command=minus)
minus.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
minus.place(x=300, y=200)
```

Button should add or subtract from counterValue resulting in it showing -1 or 2

Comment: You only ever set the label text once. Your buttons are updating the variable, but you don't update the label, so it just has its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to update the `text` property of your `Label` widget:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font

# main Window using Tk
win = Tk()

win.title("Counter")
win.geometry('500x500')

counterValue = 0

def plus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue += 1
    counter.config(text=counterValue)  # <- HERE

def minus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue -= 1
    counter.config(text=counterValue)  # <- HERE

counter = Label(win, text=counterValue)
counter.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
counter.place(x=250, y=50)

plus = Button(win, text="+", command=plus)
plus.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
plus.place(x=150, y=200)

minus = Button(win, text="-", command=minus)
minus.configure(font=("Helvetica bold", 50))
minus.place(x=300, y=200)

win.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Devler. Did one answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
def plus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue += 1
    counter['text'] = counterValue

def minus():
    global counterValue
    counterValue -= 1
    counter['text'] = counterValue

...
win.mainloop() #<--- add this
```